# Crystal Report 2008 when uploaded into Infoview doesnt underlay following section

Tags: crystal-reports, infoview

Thanks in advance, I used the 'underlay following section' feature to create a watermark using a text field. Works perfectly when viewing or printing in Crystal 2008. However when loaded into Infoview, the 'watermark' OVERLAYS all of the critical data, partially shielding it from sight, defeating the purpose entirely. Does anyone know if Infoview supports that feature?

Answer (score 0):

It should.  Is the server using the same version of CR that you are using?  You may also want to use with the ActiveX viewer instead of the DHTML viewer (AKA 'Web').

Comment: Thanks for replying. In Infoview under Preferences/Viewer, I selected Java and it corrected the problem. Active X was an option as well, but that didn't work for some reason.